# How navigate directly to Sibling widgets in Flutter without going back?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have a root widget and 3 siblings widget.

- Root

  - FooTab1
  - FooTab2
  - FooTab3

User can navigate directly from FooTab1 to FooTab2 or FooTab3 without going back through the Root widget. To achieve that, I use `pushReplacement`

My goal is that I want the Navigation Future from the root to fire only when user goes any of the three `FooTab` to `Root` (back button)

However, it fires immediately when I go from `FooTab1` to `Tab2` or `Tab3`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch:
            Colors.blue, // This is the primary color of your application.
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => FooTab1(),
            ),
          );
          print(
              "This should be printed only if going back from FooTab1, FooTab2, FooTab3");
          print(
              "But instead it is printed immediately when going back from FooTab1 to FooTab2");
        },
        child: const Text("Go to FooTab1"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FooTab1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooTab1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FooTab1'),
      ),
      
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => FooTab2(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: const Text("Go to FooTab2"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FooTab2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooTab2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FooTab2'),
      ),
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => FooTab3(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: const Text("Go to FooTab3"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FooTab3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooTab3({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FooTab3'),
      ),
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => FooTab1(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: const Text("Go to FooTab1"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

I found a temporary working solution using a dummy proxy widget between `Root` and `Tabs` but it creates a not nice looking transition through a blank screen whenever user goes back to `Root`

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

as mentioned in the comment, if we dont want to initiate all the children at the same time, we can use `switch case`

you can read my little experinment here: see my highligth at point 2 : https://medium.com/easyread/my-october-flutter-notes-2-6e0c78cf2e56

code:

```
body: Builder(
  builder: (context) {
    switch (activePageIdx) {
      case 0:
        return Page1();
      case 1:
        return Page2();
       //....rest of your screen
      default:
        return  const SizedBox();
     }
  },
));
```

> every time we change switch the page, it will initiated. If its a
> `StatefullWidget` the `initState()` method will also invoked

---

Im not sure i can get clearly your purpose.

but you may try this:

- use `IndexedStack` to wrap your tab widgget.
- navigate them as children
- you can navigate between children without back to root
- the printed message on the root, only print when we the back button are pressed and back to the root screen

the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch:
            Colors.blue, // This is the primary color of your application.
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => BuilderChildTab(),
            ),
          );
          print(
              "This should be printed only if going back from FooTab1, FooTab2, FooTab3");
          print(
              "But instead it is printed immediately when going back from FooTab1 to FooTab2");
        },
        child: const Text("Go to FooTab1"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BuilderChildTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuilderChildTab({super.key});

  @override
  State<BuilderChildTab> createState() => _BuilderChildTabrState();
}

class _BuilderChildTabrState extends State<BuilderChildTab> {
  int _selectedIdx = 0;
  @override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IndexedStack(index: _selectedIdx, children: [
      FooTab1(
        onTap: () {
          _selectedIdx = 1; // go to FooTab2
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      FooTab2(
        onTap: () {
          _selectedIdx = 2; // go to FooTab3
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      FooTab3(
        onTap: () {
          _selectedIdx = 0; // go to FooTab1
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

class FooTab1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooTab1({super.key, this.onTap});
  final VoidCallback? onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FooTab1'),
      ),
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onTap,
        child: const Text("Go to FooTab2"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FooTab2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooTab2({super.key, this.onTap});
  final VoidCallback? onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FooTab2'),
      ),
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onTap,
        child: const Text("Go to FooTab3"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FooTab3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooTab3({super.key, this.onTap});
  final VoidCallback? onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FooTab3'),
      ),
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onTap,
        child: const Text("Go to FooTab1"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I use new widget `BuilderChildTab` because your `FooTab` widget has their own `Appbar`.
it they has same `Appbar` actually you can wrap them as a `body` widget

Comment: The question asks for Navigation, This is not navigating, it instantiated the 3 widgets at the same time and switches view between them. My app requires  navigation (I can give more context explaining why if needed but I believe the reason doesn't matter the question)

Comment: yeah, with `IndexedStack` will initiate all the children at the same time.   But if you want only active child is initiated, you can use `switch case`. I have wrote an article about it .

Comment: updated my answer, let me know if its not fit to your needs @TSR